# Moshi с Retrofit отправляю пустой запрос когда ожидается {null,null}

Tags: java, android, kotlin, api, retrofit

Приложение шлет мои координаты постоянно, логика завязана на чем, когда мы отключается геолокация
на сервер вместо координат должны отправиться нулы ожидается `{"latitude":null,"longitude":null}`
А отправляется `{}`

Код такой

Модель

```
@Serializable
data class PointBody(
    @Json(name = "latitude") val latitude: Double?,
    @Json(name = "longitude") val longitude: Double?
)
```

Запрос

```
 @POST(Path.LOCATION)
    suspend fun sendPoint(
        @Body point: PointBody
    )
```

Retorift

```
private fun provideRetrofit(moshi: Moshi, client: OkHttpClient) = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl("Base")
    .build()
```

Moshi

```
private fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}
```

Где-то нашел что KotlinJsonAdapterFactory() ответственен за такое поведение как его отключить именно к данной модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было написание своего адаптера для Moshi

Адаптер

```
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class SerializeNulls

class SerializeNullsFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation?>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        val nextAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(
            annotations,
            SerializeNulls::class.java
        ) ?: return null
        return moshi.nextAdapter<Any>(this, type, nextAnnotations).serializeNulls()
    }
}
```

Модель

```
@Serializable
data class PointBody(
    @SerializeNulls val latitude: Double?,
    @SerializeNulls val longitude: Double?
)
```

Moshi

```
private fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(SerializeNullsFactory())
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}
```